# Django Configuration in python 2.7 + installation 

Tags: django, installation, python-2.7

I did goggling for at-least 2 hours. I did go through with the documentation of Django and Installation Guide properly but still not succeed to configure Django in my system. I need help

I've windows-07, python 2.7 and want to configure Django 1.4.1 in my system.

**What I did till time?**

1.installed successfully python 2.7

checked the version by

```
import sys
print sys.version
```

2. Now, downloaded and unzipped Django (official version 1.4.1) and put this directory in my C Drive (where folder python 27 resides)

I did run setup.py of Django through cmd but still not succeed.
Can any one give me suggestion what I'm doing wrong here?
Any help is welcome, thanks

Comment: What's the problem with the install? What errors does it give you?

Comment: That i have not get till time but after installation when I run setup.py after that in IDLE I'm writing import django (it's not working) it give me import error "No module named django"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for windows-7, official version of django... have you tried this command in cmd !

in directory of django -> python setup.py install